useState call is not destructured into value + setter pair sonarcloud issue
I am running sonarcloud in my react code.
my sample code is
interface PRScoreObject {
    salesAmt?: any; // date-type is number
    target?: any; // date-type is number or object with key value pair
    achievement: any; // date-type is number or object with key value pair
    crscore: any; // date-type is number
  }
const initializePRScoreObj = (): PRScoreObject => ({
    salesAmt: '',
    target: '',
    achievement: '',
    crscore: '',
  });

my state
const [prScoreObj, setPRscoreObj] = useState<PRScoreObject>(initializePRScoreObj);
i will update my state in onClick event or onChange events
setPRscoreObj({...prScoreObj,target, salesAmt, achievement: achObj});
I am getting this error useState call is not destructured into value + setter pair how to fix this issue


I would guess it's a eslint warning: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/hook-use-state.md
You should name them as [prScoreObj, setPrScoreObj]

Please show your useState command, which throws the error

@TusharShahi I am getting this error only useState call is not destructured into value + setter pair while running the sonarcloud i am getting this error

Have you tried renaming them to [prScoreObj, setPrScoreObj] ?

@alexwbt your correct its working. sorry for the late response thanks you

const [PageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1); // throws sonar issue
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1); // No Error

But if you still want capital letter state variables:
import * as React from "react";
const [PageNumber, setPageNumber] = React.useState(1);

